# Where do I find the default baud rate for screen (on Mac)?

Tags: macos, usb, gnu-screen, serial-port, embedded

This command works fine:

```
screen /dev/ttyS
```

I don't need to set a specific baud rate. Do you know what the default baud rate is, or where I can find the default baud rate that is used?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34233066/change-the-baud-rate-stty-on-mac-terminal

Answer (score 0):

I connected to a SiLabs USB to UART adapter on a Mac and got 9600 baud as the default. If I set it too high such as 460800 it defaulted to 9600 as well. You can add the baud you want after the device like screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 230400.